# My app was rejected. Where can i find the advertisingidentifier or ASidentifiermanager?

Tags: ios, app-store

To tell you a little about my app, I have a free version and a pro version without ads.  The free version was accepted in the App Store, but the pro version was not. In the pro version, I just left out all the Advertising IDs.  I am using Revmob, Chartboost and AppLovin.  After submitting, I got this message from Apple:

> **"PLA 3.3.12"**
>
> We found your app uses the iOS *Advertising Identifier* but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, **section 3.3.12** of the [iOS Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/terms/) states:

> "You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the *Advertising Identifier*, and any information obtained through the use of the *Advertising Identifier*, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the *Advertising Identifier*, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior *Advertising Identifier* and any derived information with the reset *Advertising Identifier*."
>
> Please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:

```
class: ASIdentifierManager
selector: advertisingIdentifier
framework: AdSupport.framework
```

> If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please remove the *Advertising Identifier* from your app until you have included ad functionality.
>
> To help locate the *Advertising Identifier*, use the “nm” tool. For information on the “nm” tool, open a terminal window and enter, “man nm.”
>
> If you do not have access to the libraries source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using the "`strings`" or "`otool`" command line tools. The "`strings`" tool lists the methods that the library calls, and "`otool -ov`" will list the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides."

I don't really know much about coding.  I just know the basics with Xcode.  Can anyone help me figure out what to do to find the problem code so I can remove it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Statistics suggest that using in-app purchases to remove advertising has a better conversion rate than having separate free and pro versions. Instead of maintaining two versions of your app and removing chunks from the pro one, why not try this approach?

Comment: I do have in-app purchases to remove ads in the free version but to your dismay, I sill make a decent amount of money on the pro version.

Comment: Good for you! I assumed, since you'd had the pro version rejected, that this was a new app.

Comment: I agree and disagree. What about when you want to add lots of other features to the PRO version (other than just removing adverts). Surely it doesn't make sense to keep on using iAPs to add more and more features to the app.

Answer (score 1):

Remove revmob, Chartboost and AppLovin from your pro version. Unlink AdSupport.framework. Also, if you use Flurry or other analytics sdk, make sure you have the latest version. My app was rejected for the same reason because Flurry Analytics was using advertising identifier under the hood. Few days ago Flurry released an updated version of their sdk to address this issue. That can also happen for other analytics platforms, like google.

Comment: If I delete AdSupport.framework, it just freezes on the launch screen.  This may be a dumb question, but how do I delete Revmob Chartboost and Applovin?  Do i just delete "applovin-ios-sdk-2.0.94", "Chartboost" and "RevMobAds.framework" on the left side panel?

Answer (score 0):

Its not always using the AdSupport.framework usage reject the app. I think its the way you are using.

One of my app was using advertising identifier, but for solely different purpose. I was not using any third party ads.

The important thing is that you are avoiding Apple iAds but using third party ads, thats why your app may be rejected.